# Formatting index in c++

Tags: c++, indexing, format

I ve got a for loop and I want to format the index i (which takes values 1-1000) to 0001-1000. I came across formatting index solution using printf and cout but I want to do so for a string name. I am trying something like that, but it doesn't working:

```
   for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){

      string num2string = setfill('0') +setw(4) + i; 
   }
```

How can I convert setfill and setw to string objects??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string stream if you want to get a string as a result and still use setfill and setw:

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
  std::ostringstream stringStream;
  stringStream << std::setfill ('0') << std::setw (4) << i;
  std::string num2string = stringStream.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setfill` and `setw` are [IO manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) that must be applied to an IO stream using the `<<` operator. In your case, you need to create a [`stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to redirect stream operations to string. For example, this prints `0013`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string num2string(int n)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << n;
  return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << num2string(13);
}
```

Comment: @FereRes `iomanip` is required for `std::setfill` and `std::setw`.

Comment: @FereRes In standard C++, you must include the header. For example, on g++ 4.6, removing `#include <iomanip>` results in compilation error with the compiler complaining that `setfill` and `setw` are not members of `std`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::ostringstream` instead. `std::string` itself does not have many formatting helpers. It is a `ostream` (like `cout` is an instance thereof):

```
std::ostringstream ss; // Note: not creating it everytime to repeat less work
ss << setfill('0');
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    ss.str("");
    ss << setw(4) << i;
    string num2string = ss.str();
}
```

Unfortunately for your case, `setw` is not preserved in the state of `stringstream`, hence you have to set it everytime.

A 3rd-party alternative would be the [boost format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/):

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
....

    string num2string = boost::format("%04d")%i;
```